# What does "Don´t you dare play the strings of my heart" mean?

Tags: idioms

What does the sentence "Don´t you dare play the strings of my heart" mean??
I want to say something like: "do not try to provoke any emotions".

Can I use the sentence above to express this meaning??

Hope you can help me.
I´m looking forward to your comments.

Love from Germany

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means not to mess around with the feelings of a vulnerable person or take that person's feelings lightly. Often used in the romantic sense.

Yes you can, but it's better to say:

> Don't you dare play with my heart strings.

or

> Don't you dare play **with** the strings of my heart.

Answer (score 1):

**heart-strings** (n.) [etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/heart-strings)

> also heartstrings, late 15c., in old anatomy, "the tendons and nerves
>   that brace the heart;" from heart (n.) + string (n.). Transferred and
>    **figurative sense "strongest affections, most intense feelings" is from  1590s.**

Yes you can use it as such ... but @aesking provided better AmE grammatical structure in an answer to this post.

the idiom goes as follows:  **tear/tug/pull at/on (one's)/the heartstrings** Thefreedictionary.com

> To elicit strong feelings of sympathy or fondness.

Answer (score -1):

Play with the person's emotions. It's used in romantic relationships, or where deep emotion is evoked.

Comment: So it is okay to use "strings of my heart" instead of "heart strings"??